# How to validate array(matrix) format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, validation, matrix

I am making page for array multiplication, and I need to validate array format before action. Textbox should accept only arrays in this format: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` - the matrix array of row arrays.

I tried with regex, but I really can't do it. Is there any other way?

Comment: what validation are you trying to build?

Comment: I need to validate array format, which should be like this: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]].

Comment: Can the array element be greater than single digit numbers? E.g., `[[1111,2,3],[7777,4,5],[0000,6,7]]`?

Comment: Yes. Negative numbers also.

Comment: Can space characters be included `[1, 2, 3]`? Are you trying to check if only numbers are input?

Comment: No, spaces are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the regex given below

```
^ +\[ ([\[[ +\d+ +,]+ +] +,)+ +\[[ +\d+ ,]+ +] +]$
```

all in one final solution...

can manage spaces...

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work for array like this: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] or [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9], [10,11,12] ..

Comment: hold on let me handle this

Comment: so this one helps for your second condition... you put in the comment

Comment: This looks cool :) One more thing: can you make it accept spaces between numbers and arrays?

Comment: Doesn't deal with decimal numbers, negative numbers, numbers that start with a plus, numbers in scientific notation, newlines, tabs, ...

Comment: oh!!! come-on!!!!!!!!!! don't take it on heart... actually stackoverflow was saying to add more characters... to publish that answer.. that's the reason i added those lines....... sometime it becomes necessary to fool machine...

Comment: but i like the way you replied... @trincot

Answer (score 1):

It can be in the proximity of

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
  valid = arr.every(a => Array.isArray(a) && a.length === 3 && a.every(item => typeof item === "number"));
console.log(valid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse()`, `Array.prototype.every()`

```js
var res;
try {
  res = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("input").value)
        .every(function(arr) {return arr.every(Number)});
  console.log(res);
} 
// handle `JSON.parse()` error
catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="[[1,-2,3],[4,5,-6],[7,8,99999]]">
```

Comment: very cool.. unfortunatelly doesn't work when there is array items in the arrays such as `<input type="text" value="[[[1],-2,3],[4,5,-6],[7,[8],99999]]">`

Comment: @Redu `[[[1],-2,3],[4,5,-6],[7,[8],99999]]` is not the format of array described  by OP?

Comment: OP says Textbox should accept only arrays in this format: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`. To me this means no `[1,{0:2},3]` and no `[1,[2],3]`. Am i thinking wrong..?

Comment: @Redu Though that format can also be handled by slightly adjusting `javascript` at Answer.

Comment: @Redu Not sure if you are "thinking wrong", though OP has not included those examples at Question or comments as possible input. With slight adjustments to `javascript` , either of the example inputs which you have  shared can return same result using same original pattern at Answer. Note also that your solution begins with an array as input, not a string; which would be `.value` of an `<input>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Although you already accepted an answer, I'd still like to propose this solution:

```js
function getValidArray(txt) {
    try {
        var arr = JSON.parse(txt);
    } catch (e) {}
    return Array.isArray(arr) 
           && arr.length == 3
           && arr.every( sub => Array.isArray(arr) 
                         && sub.length === 3 
                         && sub.every ( v => typeof v == 'number' ) )
           && arr;
}

// I/O for snippet:

var inp = document.querySelector('input');
var out = document.querySelector('div');

inp.oninput = function() {
    var txt = inp.value;
    var result = getValidArray(txt);
    out.textContent = result ? JSON.stringify(result) : 'invalid';    
};
inp.oninput();
```

```css
input { width: 100% }
```

```html
Array: <input value="  [[1,88,-45.2],     [1.2e+2, 1e-1,-0.9],[  0,22, 1.33]  ]">
<div></div>
```

This test succeeds when the text represents a 3x3 array of numbers.

It will accept white-space to occur around numbers, commas, ... and will accept negative and decimal values, even scientific notation.